# Enable php-gmp for php

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to configure an AWS AMI instance. In some of the PHP code I use the gmp function, so I installed the relevant package using the following command.

```
yum install php71-gmp
```

I have restarted apache, but this doesn't work or give any difference. Still getting the error Call to undefined function gmp.

Any clue how I can add this extension? In the /etc/php.ini there is no extension list..

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer from Amazon Support Center

Create a `something.config` file inside a `.ebextensions` folder at the root directory of your project and put this code inside:

```
packages:
  yum:
    php70-gmp: []
```